# Git push to a folder

Tags: git

I am creating a port of an app for win mobile 7 and I would like to push my master to "master/platforms/windowsmobile7" of the remote server.

is there a simple way of doing this without creating a whole tree structure and moving my project directory to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local copy of the remote repository is supposed to be a clone of it.
You don't "push a folder" or a file, or a tree. You push commits. These are differences between two states of the repository.

So, I would say :

- I don't think there's a way of doing what you want to do
- It wouldn't be good practice

If you want to have sub projects in a repository, usually [git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you just want another branch: `git checkout -b windowsmobile7`  It's generally recommended to try to factor out platform-specific code into modules, though.  That makes it easier to maintain common code over time.